# Python Save SQL query to excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 to query a database and return a table of data. I need to then write that data to a .xlsx file.

I had it writing to a .csv really nicely using:

```
with open("file_name.csv", "w") as file:
    csv_writer = writer(file)
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

This works fine, the only issue is that I now need to open the .csv and save as a new .xlsx so its a step I want to cut out.

I'm trying to use pandas:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
df.to_excel("file_name.xlsx")
```

But all numbers are being stored as text so I now need to go back in and refresh the cells for excel to realise its an integer or float?

Also tried with openpyxl, this works better but still stored the date column as text so I still need to go in and refresh the cells for excel to recognise it as a date.

I thought it might have been an issue with how psycopg2 pulls the data but its not an issue for .csv so why is it a problem for .xlsx? This is probably just my lack of understanding the difference between the two files types. Does anyone have a solution for saving as a .xlsx but retaining all the correct formatting?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the `DataFrame` you can specify "converters" for excel:

```py
converters = {
    'name': str,
    'ages': int,
    'score': float
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=headers, converters=converters)
df.to_excel("file_name.xlsx")
```

Where the keys of the converters dict are the column names in the DataFrame.